# How to write a regular expression to match this pattern?

Tags: regex

Keep

```
2倍
3倍
10倍
4.5倍
```

`0.2倍` excluded

I want to match larger than 1 but exclude smaller than 1, I tried `[2-9]\..倍|[2-9]倍`, but it is not perfect, so I am here to ask for some help.

Comment: Try this: [1-9]\d*\.?\d倍

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?倍`

This should except any number as long as the leftmost digit is not 0

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one :

```
^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?倍$
```

`^[1-9]` forces number to be bigger than 1

`\d*` optional additional digits before dot

`(\.\d+)$` end of string can be with or without decimal points.

Comment: `[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?倍` is fine as long as you don't expect negative numbers in the input. If necessary, add start of line character: `^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?倍`

Comment: @kolejnik Thanks, I updated my answer to be more strict.